# Замена mail() это реально?

Tags: php, email

Поймал себя на мысли, что нужно использовать рассылку на почту, для подтверждения почты и восстановления пароля.

Пользуюсь хостинг, который имеет почтовый сервис, но он на платной версии. Так как мой сайт только для моего хобби. Не вижу смысла тратить деньги на платный хостинг.

Вопрос следующий. Я как-то могу использовать сторонний сервер для отправки писем или чем-то заменить mail()?

Comment: Да, по SMTP подключайтесь куда хотите

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать сторонний SMTP сервер. Если у вас нет доступа к настройкам PHP то использовать функцию `mail()` вы не сможете. Потребуется использовать компоненты для отправки почты, например PHPMailer или SwiftMailer (ну или самостоятельно написать, если очень хочется)

См. также:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer